# Action on a torus

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, riemannian-geometry, group-actions

I was asked the following question: suppose that $M= T^{2n}$ a torus of dimension 2n. And let $\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z} \subset \mathrm{Homeo(M)}$ such that the space of fixed points $N=M^{\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}}$ is a closed connected manifold of dimension n.

Intuitively I would say that $N$ should be homemorphic to $T^n$, is there a simple proof?

**If it can help you can assume that everything is smooth.**

Comment: $Z/2Z\in Homeo(M)$ is senseless and absurd? Do you mean $Z/2Z\subset Homeo(M)$, which is already an abuse of notation? This is inclusion, not belonging. Anyway I'd strongly recommend avoiding such abuse of notation (if you have two such subgroups, how do you write it??) and it's easy to write $C\subset Homeo(M)$ a subgroup of order 2".

Comment: By the way, technically the empty set may be viewed as a closed submanifold of dimension $n$. I expect you assume the fixed point set to be non-empty (to avoid trivial counterexamples).

Comment: This is almost surely false. In general, the best one can hope for is to control $Z_2$-homology of the fixed-point set. Compare this with the result (due to Lowell Jones) that **every** finite $2$-acyclic complex is homotopy-equivalent to the fixed-point set of a smooth involution acting on a disk of some dimension.

Comment: To add to Moishe Kohan's comment: you can start with any $G$-action on the torus whose fixed point set has sufficiently large dimension and then take equivariant connected sum with a suitable $G$-action on the sphere. The latter can have very complicated fixed point set, see e.g. "Smooth actions of finite Oliver groups on spheres", Topology, 2003, https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0040938302000083.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek I do not understand your comment, by hypothesis N is already a closed connected n-manifold.

Comment: @GMS: When you take equivariant connected sums of $G$-actions on $T^m$ and $S^m$, the result is a $G$-action on $T^m=T^m\# S^m$ whose fixed point set is the connected sum of their fixed point sets.  The fixed point set on $S^m$ could be e.g. a homology $k$-sphere $\Sigma$, so if the given action on $T^m$ has $T^k$ as the fixed point set, the resulting action on $T^m$ has $\Sigma\# T^k$ as fixed point set. You can read more on equivariant connected sum in section 3 of  https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0302221.pdf where the setting is very close to your setting.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek now I think  I do understand,  you should write an answer based on your comment!

Comment: For the special case $n=2$, this does hold. The Lefschetz fixed point theorem implies that the fixed point set would have Euler characteristic $0$, and hence must be a torus. This doesn't contradict Igor and Moishe's examples due to the lack of interesting $Z_2$ homology spheres.

Comment: @DannyRuberman I do agree!

Comment: @GSM: please feel free to write your own answer; sorry I am busy with the start of the term. I found a relevant paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/0710.2612.pdf of Edmonds who extends Smith theory to $\mathbb Z_p$ actions on tori, and in particular shows in theorem 2.1 that every component of the fixed point set of a $p$-group action on a torus is a homology $\mathbb Z_p$-torus, and moreover all components have the same dimension. There are many other nice facts in the paper.